# How to post data of 'content-type application/json' to slim php rest service

Tags: php, json, rest, slim

i am having issue for posting data of mime type `content-type application/json` from Chrome Advance rest Client to slim framework web service.
I tried these codes to send in `application/json`

```
$app->post('/register', function() use ($app) {
            $app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\ContentTypes());            
            $params = $app->request->getBody();
            $name = $params->name;
            $email = $params->email;
            $password = $params->password;
            ...});
```

tried this also

```
$params = json_decode($app->request()->getBody());


 var_dumb($params); //get NULL value here
```

Getting errors of

```
Trying to get property of non-object to this `$name = $params->name;`
```

Please help me how to catch application/json format of data? 
Thank you

Comment: The error you're showing is related to first part of your first snippet. Try to comment it and try to work only on the second one.

Comment: Mind sharing the JSON object your are submitting ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the above details, assuming your raw JSON looks something like this

```
{"name":"John Smith", "mail":"jhon@mail.com", "password":"foobar"}
```

You can access your params **array** like this

```
$app->post('/register', function () use ($app) {
$params =  $app->request->getBody() ;
$params = array_filter($params);

if(!empty($params)){
    $name = $params['name'];
    $mail = $params['mail'];
    $pass = $params['password'];

   // print $name;
  }

})->name("register");
```

or if you are posting in Advanced Rest client via `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you can use `$app->request->post();` to access your array

```
$app->post('/register/', function () use ($app) {

   $userInfo = $app->request()->params() ;
   //or
   $userInfo =  $app->request->post() ;
   $name = $userInfo['name'];
   $mail = $userInfo['email'];
   $pass = $userInfo['password'];

 // print $name

})->name("register");
```